# Differentiating $\frac{1}{7}\cos^4(x^2+2x+3)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, derivatives, trigonometry

I'm trying to differentiate this function using the chain rule, but not sure whether I'm doing it right.

I did the following:

I let $u = (x^2 +2x+3)$ and $y = \cos^4u$,

$\frac{du}{dx} = 2x +2$, $\frac{dy}{du} = -\sin^4u$

$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} \times \frac{du}{dx}$ = $-\sin^4 \times 2x+2$ = $(1/7) \times -\sin^4(2x+2)$

Comment: $[\cos^4 u]' \ne -\sin^4 u$.  You need to use the chain rule on *that* as well.  $v(x)= x^4$ so we have $[\cos^4 u]' =[v(\cos u)]' = v'(\cos u) \cos' u = 4\cos^3 u\cdot(-\sin x) = -4\sin x\cos^3 x$.

Comment: what happens with the (1/7) in the beggining does that just stay the same?

Comment: The seven is a contstant.

Comment: Chain rule:  If $\color{red}{h(x)} = \color{green}{\frac 17}x$ then $\color{red}{h'(x)} = \color{green}{\frac 17}$.  So  $[\color{green}{\frac 17} f(x)]' = [\color{red}{h}((f(x))]' = \color{red}{h'}(f(x)\color{red}{)}(f'(x))=\color{green}{\frac 17}f'(x)$. Which... is a convoluted way of saying something that you always knew anyway.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac {d\cos^4 u}{du}\ne -\sin^4 u$.

Let $v(x) = x^4$ then we have

SO if you have $\cos^4 u = v(\cos u)$ then

$\frac {d\cos^4 u}{du} = \frac {d v(\cos u)}{du} = \frac {d v(\cos u)}{d(\cos u)} \frac d{\cos u}{du}=$

$4(\cos u)^3\cdot (-\sin u)=$

$-4\sin u\cos^3 u$.

Doing it via the chain rule is

$[\frac{1}{7}cos^4(x^2+2x+3)]'=$

$\frac 17[4(\cos^3(x^2+2x+3))(-\sin(x^2 + 2x + 3)(2x + 2)]=$

$-\frac 47\cos^3(x^2 + 2x + 3)(\sin(x^2 + 2x+3)(2x + 2)$

.....

If you want to be *really* pendantic

Let $f(x) = x^2 +2x + 3$

Let $g(x) = \cos x$

Let $h(x) = x^4$

Let $i(x) = \frac 17 x$

So we have $[i(h(g(f(x)))]' = i'(h(g(f(x)))\cdot h'(g(f(x)))\cdot g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$

$i'(w) = [\frac 17 w]' = \frac 17$.

$h'(w) = [w^4]' = 4w^3$.

$g'(w)= [\cos w]' =-\sin w$

$f'(w) = (w^2 +2w + 3)' = 2w+2$

So  $[i(h(g(f(x)))]' = i'(h(g(f(x)))\cdot h'(g(f(x)))\cdot g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)=$

$\frac 17\cdot (4(g(f(x)))^3) \cdot (-\sin(f(x)) \cdot (2x + 2) =$

$\frac 17 \cdot 4(\cos(x^2 + 2x + 3))^3 \cdot (-\sin(x^2 + 2x + 3))\cdot (2x+2) =$

$-\frac 47 \cos^3(x^2 + 2x + 3)(\sin(x^2 + 2x + 3)(2x+2)$.

Oh... I guess we should factor out the $2$ from $2x + 2$...

$= -\frac 87 \cos^3(x^2 + 2x + 3)(\sin(x^2 + 2x + 3)(x+1)$.

....

And I suppose proving $[i(h(g(f(x)))]' = i'(h(g(f(x)))\cdot h'(g(f(x)))\cdot g'(f(x))\cdot f'(x)$ by multiple applications of the chain rule can be done.

Let $h(g(f(x))) = j(x)$ then $[i(j(x))]' = i'(j(x))j'(x)$.

If $k(x) = g(f(x))$ then $j(x) = k(g(x))$ and $j'(x) = k'(g(x))g'(x)$.

And $k'(x) = g'(f(x))f'(x)$.  SO the result follows.

======

But one can drive oneself *NUTS* paying that much attention to detail.  The comes a point where sums,constants, and powers should be automatic:

If $h(x) = c\cdot (f(g))^k$

then $h'(x) = ck(f(g(x)))^{k-1}f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$,

shouldn't be tooooo difficult a result to accept off the bat.

(which is our case with $c = \frac 17, k = 4, f=\cos; g(x) = x^2 + 2x + 3$.

It *shouldn't* be difficult for a student to follow that

$[\frac 17\cos^4(x^2 + 2x + 3)]'=$

$\frac 17\cdot 4\cos^3(x^2+2x+3)\cdot(-\sin(x^2 + 2x + 3))\cdot (2x  +2)$.

Answer (score 0):

I will write $D_x$ instead of $\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}$.So, you want to calculate
$$D_x\left[ \frac{1}{7}\cos^4(x^2+2x+3)\right]=\frac{1}{7}D_x\left[\cos^4(x^2+2x+3)\right].$$
I will leave the $1/7$ and multiply it again at the end. Set $g=\cos(x^2+2x+3)$. Now that's
$$D_g\left[g^4\right]\cdot D_x \left[\cos(x^2+2x+3)\right] = 4g^3 D_x \left[\cos(x^2+2x+3)\right].$$
You can evaluate the derivative by the  normal chain rule. Substitute $g$ back again:
$$4g^3\left(-(2x+2)\sin(x^2+2x+3)\right) = 4\left(\cos(x^2+2x+3)\right)^3\left(-(2x+2)\sin(x^2+2x+3)\right).$$
Don't forget to multiply the $1/7$. You should end up with:
$$-\frac{4\cos^3(x^2+2x+3)\sin(x^2+2x+3)(2x+2)}{7}$$

Answer (score 0):

The function that you hace to derive is the composition of three two function: $f$, $g$, $h$.
In effect $\frac{1}{7}\cos^4(x^2+2x+3)=\frac{1}{7}h(g(f(x)))$, with $f(x)=x^2+2x+3$, $g(x)=cos(x)$, $h(x)=x^4$.
So applying the chain rule of derivation to this composition the derivative will be =$-\frac{4}{7}\cos^3{(x^2+2x+3)}\sin{(x^2+2x+3)}*(2x+2)$

Answer (score 0):

You should consider
$$u=x^2+2x+3$$
$$y=\cos(u)$$
$$z=y^4$$

and

$$\frac{dz}{dx}=\frac{dz}{dy}\frac{dy}{dx}=4y^3\color{red}{\frac{dy}{dx}}$$

$$\color{red}{\frac{dy}{dx}}=\frac{dy}{du}\frac{du}{dx}=-\sin(u)\frac{du}{dx}$$

$$\frac{du}{dx}=(2x+2)$$

you can finish.

Answer (score 0):

Your $\frac{dy}{du}$ is wrong. $\cos^4(u) = \left((\cos u)^4\right),\ $ so let $v = \cos u\ $ and $\ y = v^4.\ $ Then,

$\frac{dy}{dv}= 4v^3,\ $ and $\frac{dv}{du}= -\sin(u).$ Therefore:

$\frac{dy}{du} = \frac{dy}{dv} \times \frac{dv}{du} = 4v^3  \times -\sin(u) = 4(\cos (u))^3  \times -\sin(u) = -4(\sin (u))\cos^3(u).$

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember to $\color{blue}{\text{take the constant out}}$ and $\color{red}{\text{apply the chain rule}}$:

\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{7}\cos^4(x^2+2x+3) \\
&=\color{blue}{\frac{1}{7}\frac{d}{dx}(\cos^4(x^2+2x+3))}\\
&\color{red}{=4(\cos(x^4(x^2+2x+3))^3\frac{d}{dx}(\cos(x^2+2x+3))}\\
&=\frac{1}{7}\cdot4(\cos(x^2(x^2+2x+3))^3(-\sin(x^2+2x+3)(2x+2))\\
&=\boxed{-\frac{4}{7}\cos^3(x^2+2x+3)\sin(x^2+2x+3)(2x+2))}\\
\end{align}

**EDIT:**
Thanks @fleablood for pointing that out!

Comment: Technically speaking you can kee the constant in and apply the chain rule one more time.  If $h(x) = \frac 17 x$ then $\frac 17 f(x) = h(f(x))$ and $[\frac 17 f(x)]' = [h(f(x))]' = h'(f(x))\cdot f'(x) = \frac 17 \cdot f'(x) = \frac 17 f'(x)$.  But one can drive oneself *NUTS* paying that much attention to detail.  The comes a point where sums,constants, and powers should be automatic:  If $h(x) = c\cdot (f(g))^k$ then $h'(x) = ck(f(g(x)))^{k-1}f'(g(x))\cdot g'(x)$, shouldn't be tooooo difficult a result to accept off the bat.